# Detect new line if no \n in the last line in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have data in buffer and I am processing it line by line.

In buf I have following data

```
name,email,phn
test1,test1@example.com,1234567890
test2,testt2@example.com,1234567891
```

The last line doesn't have new line so my loop is working only 2 times but it should work for 3 times because buf has 3 line of record

To detect line break I am using below script

```
   var stream = fs.createReadStream('file.txt', { flags: 'r', encoding: 'utf-8' });
     stream.on('data', async function (d) {
     buf += d.toString();
     var pos;
    while ((pos = buf.indexOf('\n')) >= 0) { 
    if (pos == 0) { 
     buf = buf.slice(1); // discard it
     continue; 
    }
    var line = buf.slice(0, pos).substr(0, buf.slice(0, pos).length);
    //processing logic
        }
```

Comment: Is `buf` a nodejs buffer object or a string?

Comment: @jfriend00 Edited question with extra details

Comment: FYI, there are multiple modules that already read a file line by line and solve everything you're asking about here.  I'd suggest using one of those.  the `readline` module is built into nodejs (though it isn't my favorite).  There are also several others on npm that make this really simple.

Comment: @jfriend00 my script is working in all case. Issue only comes when there is no new line in last line of file

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) it (to make sure the ending newline is gone), then to split it on `'\n'`:

```js
const lines = buf.trim().split("\n");

for (const line of lines) {
    console.log("found line:", line);
}
```

If you want to keep using `indexOf` for whatever reason, then just add a single `'\n'` to the end (trimming the string first to make sure you don't end up with two `\n`s):

```js
buf = buf.trim() + "\n";
```

Comment: If this is a nodejs Buffer object, there is no `.trim()` method.

Comment: @jfriend00 Judging from the fact that it's a CSV, I'd wager that it's a plaintext string and not a buffer. But, if it is a buffer then you could homeroll a `trim` by checking the last index.

Comment: I can't split it by \n because my data may have multiple \n inside quotes . I think It good to add \n at the end. But one problem is my data is getting modified after adding \n

Comment: You could convert buffer to string like `buf.toString()`

Comment: @ryanve I am already converting buf += d.toString(); Please check my question

Comment: @user13000875 please show an "\n inside quotes" example in your sample data

Comment: @ryanve I disn't get your point. Also for large file data will come in many buffer. but "\n" should only add for last buffer